# Проблема при установке MikTex

Tags: latex

При установке через [сетевой инсталлер](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/setup/windows-x64/setup-2.9.6637-x64.exe) появляется ошибка  потери соединения с сервером. [image: ошибка]

Как это решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этому может быть много причин и однозначно сказать нельзя. Его могут блокировать: антивирус, виндовый фаервол - эти двое лечатся. Хуже, если блокировка идет на уровне провайдера интернета, с этим уже сложно бороться.

Попробуйте для начала отключить антивирус (и/или фаервол) на время установки. Если не поможет... Сетвой инсталлер работает в 2 этапа. Первый этап - загрузка. И загрузку можно выполнить на другом компьютере (на работе?). В зависимости от типа инсталлера (32 или 64 битный) в итоге должно получиться от 1 Гб до примерно 1.5 Гб. Может и несколько больше, я давно новую версию не стаскивал. Я это к тому, чтобы был примерный ориентир. И по времени это может занять минут 15-40, в зависимости от скорости соединения.

Если удастся загрузить, то надо забрать весь подкаталог (лучше все упаковать с легким уровнем сжатия, т.к. один большой файл носить и копировать проще, чем 2000+ мелких файлов. Для второго этапа надо запускать тот же инсталлер, но выбрать в нем полную установку (а не загрузку).

Если не получится так скачать, можно попросить кого-нибудь (да хотя бы и меня) выложить дистрибутив на какой-то сетевой диск (гугл или яндекс).

Или как вариант, можно вместо миктеха установить TeXLive -  у него можно скачать дистрибутив в виде DVD образа. По количеству пакетов он должен быть не хуже миктеха (но под windows я с ним дела не имел).

Comment: действительно скачала с работы файлы всё нормально, но при установке появилась ошибка : The directory ... is not a valid installation source. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, при установке неверно указали каталог с пакетами... По идее, когда setup находится в том же подкаталоге, то он должен правильно определять, откуда брать пакеты. А насколько длинный путь к каталогу с пакетами? И есть ли пробелы и русские буквы в пути? Я бы предложил сделать этот путь покороче, без пробелов и без кириллицы, если дело именно в пути.

Comment: Убрала пробелы и русские названия папок - проблема осталась

Comment: Получается, что чего-то в дистрибутиве не докачалось?.. Ну или что-то не так с самим инсталлером (могли поломать и еще никто не оповестил). У меня пока нет других идей. Наверное, попробую сам стащить новую версию...

Comment: В общем, скачал я новый миктех. Оказалось уже 2.6 Гб и 3511 файлов (вместе с setup и readme). Запускается установка нормально (специально сделал ему каталог и с пробелами и русскими буквами). Ваша ошибка возникает только если файл `setup-2.9.6637-x64.exe` находится не в том же каталоге, что и пакеты.Т.е. если Вы переместите этот setup в каталог к архивам и запустите установку оттуда, то все должно заработать.

Comment: Работает только когда setup в одной папке со всеми скачанными файлами. При том только в той папке путь к которой MikTex, прописывает при первом запуске. Танцы с бубном